# Is a laptop with Bitlocker rendered useless for a thief?

Tags: security, bitlocker, tpm

I am trying to find a way to protect my Windows laptop from being reused or sold after possible theft. It is my understanding that Bitlocker can at least protect my data and keep my laptop from being wiped via USB and reused/resold.

However, can't the thief just take out the encrypted drive and replace it with a new one? Does Bitlocker protect against this in any way?

Comment: Your question contains mostly venting and commentary.  It's hard to tell what you are actually asking.  There is a sentence with a question mark, but the post suggests that you are really asking something broader.  People here can answer technical questions for you if you clearly articulate exactly what you want to know and focus the question on just that.  Please give it some thought, then revise the question to focus on what you want people here to answer.

Answer (score 2):

Bitlocker can only prevent the data on your hard drive from being read.  A drive that has been encrypted with Bitlocker can still be reformatted and reused by anyone.

While physical security is the only option to prevent laptop theft, there are products that can help you recover stolen laptops.  [LoJack for Laptops](https://homeoffice.absolute.com/) enabled devices can be traced when connected to the internet.